# Поиск строки в большом количестве файлов

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mongodb, elasticsearch

Есть порядка 1млн файлов html, примерно по 30-40 кб.
Нужно искать в них строку, до 100 символов. При этом содержимое строки заранее неизвестно, содержимое файлов самое разное и на разных языках. Полнотекстовый индекс пробовали - много чего пропускает - подстроки не всегда слова + нужна поддержка большого количества языков. По времени поиска ограничены в 10 минут.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста направление поиска решения

Comment: очень похоже на то, что пытаетесь сделать свою kibana или splunk

Comment: не очень понимаю, почему похоже

Answer (score 1):

вы знаете... наверное правильнее написать простенькй индексатор(поисковик с индексированием типа ищем все слова, и пишем в базу в каких они фалах есть) в базу для ваших файлов и по нему уже производить поиск файла... это же ад какой-то грепать миллион файлов в несколько потоков

Comment: в итоге так и сделали

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -r -P ".{1,100}" ./
```

В вопросе явно не указано, что нужно искать, только

> до 100 символов

Comment: Допустим эта страница одна из наших html, и мы ищем строку "слова +". Я понимаю что grep ом ее можно найти, но может есть лучше решения? Хранить эти файлы можно и в виде строк, этот поиск будет происходить несколько раз в час

Comment: @YuppiConsumer, XPath ваше ключевое слово. Чтобы укладываться в нужное время вам надо "умно" индексировать это всё, а может ещё и предпоиск делать, чтобы был некий кэш или промежуточный индекс.